# Couchbase KeyExistsError on replace

Tags: python, couchbase

I am getting the following error when I am trying to update an entity in couchbase:

```
 File "./*/couchbase_repository.py", line 55, in update self.repository.update(group)
self._connection.replace(couch_doc["id"], couch_doc, persist_to=1, cas=cas)
File "/opt/*/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchbase/bucket.py", line 377, in replace
persist_to=persist_to, replicate_to=replicate_to)
_KeyExistsError_0xC (generated, catch KeyExistsError): <Key=u'*', RC=0xC[The key already exists in the server. If you have supplied a CAS then the key exists with a CAS value different than speci$
```

The problem is that I don't specify the **cas** value in my code and accordingly to the couchbase-python-client source code - the default **cas** value is [zero](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/bucket.py#L365) so it should ignore cas verification.

*couchbase server version: 3.0.1 Community Edition (build-1444)*

*couchbase-python-client version: 2.0.4*

Versions of C libraries:

libcouchbase-dev:amd64 2.5.3-1

libcouchbase2-core:amd64 2.5.3-1

libcouchbase2-libevent:amd64 2.5.3-1

This is the code which calls the library:

```
    def update(self, obj, cas=0):
        obj.validate()
        couch_doc = self.serializer.serialize_to_database(obj)
        self._connection.replace(couch_doc["id"], couch_doc, persist_to=1, cas=cas)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it does look like you're specifying cas:

```
self._connection.replace(couch_doc["id"], couch_doc, persist_to=1, cas=cas)
```

Have you tried removing the `cas` parameter?

Comment: This cas value comes from default parameter value from https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/bucket.py#L376. I can't remove it since it is a library code.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear from your backtrace what was your code and what was library :)

Comment: yeah, I can see now. I have updated the question to make it less confusing.

Comment: does it work when you dont specify the cas param at all (not even the default value)?

Comment: I don't know how to ignore the cas, since it already been specified in library code https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/bucket.py#L376.

Comment: Try removing the `persist_to=1`. It may be that when trying to persist the document, _another_ mutation has also occurred on the server which would end up changing the CAS. A cas of 0 is fine. Also ensure `obj` is a Python dict or similar - if you pass a `Result` object, the CAS may be extracted from there

Comment: this error happens from time to time so I can't give you a fast response that it has fixed the issue but since in my environment the 'another mutation' is highly possible I will try to remove the persist_to=1 flag.

Comment: another alternative is to split the `replace` and `endure` operations in two; allowing you to clearly distinguish between a storage failure and a durability context